# How do I know which direction I should rotate a node in an AVL Tree?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, search-trees, balanced-search-trees, avl-trees

I'm studying AVL Trees in my programming class and we got this exercise dealing with right, left, left-right and right-left rotations as a way to check if we understand the theoretical concept of AVL Trees. We're given the numbers $100,50,25,10,37,32,200$. Creating an AVL Tree until $37$ wasn't that difficult but then I got stuck at balancing out the tree when I insert $32$. The following is my method:

[image]

Now I know that there is a conflict at $52$ but since it has 3 nodes (LRL), I don't understand how I should rotate. I think, I should get $37$ as the root node $25$ as it's left child and $52$ as it's right child but I dunno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think, I should get 37 as the root node 25 as it's left child and 52 as it's right child but I dunno.

You plan is correct.

What you need to do is a left-right rotation as shown in the third column of the table below. That is,  a left rotation at node 25 followed by a right rotation at 52. It is symmetric to the right-left rotation as shown in the fourth column and as [explained in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Double_rotation).

[image: tree rebalancing picture at wikimedia]

Answer (score 0):

Before you insert a node, you already know the insertion is forbidden.
You can rotate 52 before you insert a new node, because the insertion direction is otherwise wrong (52 has the red light 1). You can check and rotate all the nodes before you insert a new node such that all roads are as clear as possible (all green lights).

This generally means that after two insertions, the global height may increase (amorphous flip-flopping); in other words, every 2 insertion may trigger the extra height compression subroutine; such subroutines are very costly and can be the real main cost (hidden cost).

The flip-flop sequence obeys a very simple horizonal nonlinear wave equation with probablistic short pebble-rain+ripples. The height growth is like a simple dirac delta.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Can you provide a [reference](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for this use of *(amorphous) flip-flopping*? I remember the cost to restore the balance criterion to be "constant" with AVL tree insert.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Balanced AVL tree]

1st step : Left-Left rotation.
2nd & 3rd step :Left-Right Rotation.
4th step: Right-Right Rotation.
5th is Final AVL tree.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/avl_tree_algorithm.htm

Comment: Can you explain how did you know in which directions to perform the rotations?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus , a link is added for better explanation.

Comment: OK but what happens if that link breaks? We're trying to be a collection of answers: Google already does the "links to answers" thing far better than we ever could.

Comment: In that case that child will be added to same level where it was before rotation.

Comment: (`In that case that child will be added to same level where it was before rotation.` What *case*, what *child*? The link D. Richerby [was referring to](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/104137/how-do-i-know-which-direction-i-should-rotate-a-node-in-an-avl-tree/145056#comment225334_105261) was the hyperlink you planted to stand-in for an explanation.)

Comment: (For effective line-breaks in "markdown", append two spaces to the line you want a break after.)